# How to move data in colum 1 to odd positions in column 2?

Tags: excel

I have a big data and I would like to move data from column 1 to odd positions in column 2 (see the picture). Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Is that a one-time exercise? Or do you need to do this repeatedly?

Comment: Can you use the `address` function with a simple formula to calculate the row you want to reference eg `({current row} + 33)/2` where current row would be entered as 33 in row 33 then formula copied. Compose that with something that just leaves even rows blank. (Just an idea as I'm no Excel expert)

Comment: Eg `if(iseven(row()), '', `etc

Comment: @Chris Please avoid giving answers in comments. As it says when you type a comment.

Comment: Fair enough, it's just because it was a guess to give Markiff something to maybe look into, didn't think it would qualify as an answer as it is incomplete and may not be the right approach, and though I could put it as an answer, and let someone give a properly thought out one, I worry that seeing the question has an answer would prevent it being looked at if anyone searches by unanswered questions - that was my rationale but probably not a good rationale :-)

Comment: (actually probably better not to input on things I don't really know enough about TBH unless they are old questions that nobody is looking at, then a bit of a steer might be helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do this once:

- Insert a new column
- enter the numbers 1 and 3 into the first cells next to the first two data items
- use the fill handle to drag down with incrementing in steps of 2, so all data items have an odd number in the neighbouring column.
- in the same column, below the last odd number, enter 2 and in the next row 4
- use the fill handle and drag down until you have a number bigger than the last odd number.
- Now select the data column and the numbers and sort by the numbers column.
- move to your desired position and delete what you no longer need.

You can also use a formula along these lines:

```
=IF(INT(ROW()/2)=ROW()/2,INDEX(A:A,ROW()/2),"")
```

Then copy and paste as values over the data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your function can be modified a bit to get a direct one as follows: =IF(INT((ROW()+1)/2)=(ROW()+1)/2,INDEX(A:A,(ROW()+1)/2),"")